# shinybs `options` argument usage

Tags: r, twitter-bootstrap, shiny, shinybs

**The problem**

I started using `shinybs` which is great for displaying popovers or tooltips in shinyapps. However, I find the help provided with the package a bit lacking when it comes to customization.

Most functions from this package contain `options` argument  which allows "more control over how the tooltips and popovers appear". All that the help file says about the usage of this argument is that it accepts `list()` and you should see [Twitter Bootstrap 3 documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/) for more details. This documentation, however, is so robust that I got lost almost immediately.

**The question**

What is the basic logic of using `options` in `shinybs` - how do you figure out what values and in what form to pass to `options`? Does it use `CSS`, `JavaScript`, both, something else?

Could you provide some basic examples of how to customize popovers and tooltips in `shinybs` using `options` argument? For example: change height, width, background color, etc.

Comment: I think options are limited to those listed on http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_tooltip.asp (see the options section), and you cannot use options to change size/color etc. To do that, try CSS (see custom tool design section on the same page).